# How do you map JSON type data while using JPA from mapping models to mongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate OGM to map my models to my MongoDB Database. This uses JPA to do this.

The problem that I'm facing is that I receive data from an API that can have different formats. So I want to save the Data from the API directly in mongoDB without having to map it to a Class first. But this approach doesn't work.

**Festival Class**

```
@Entity
    public class Festival {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String sub_name;

    private JSONObject apiResult;

    [..]
```

The error that I'm getting is: **'Basic' attribute type should not be 'JSONObject'**

It quite obvious that Basic is not the right attribute type. But I don't know what the right attribute type and/or Object type for apiResult sould be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed. What I was trying to do is simply not possible in JPA. So i switched to Morphia https://mongodb.github.io/morphia , Morphia is an Object Document Mapper. And I'm amazed with the simplicity of the implementation and the advanced features at has.

It works way better than Hibernate OGM it you only use an mongodb database in your java program.